# Given a circle with three points (x1,y1), (x2,y2), and (x1,0) and another circle (x1,y1), (x2,y2) and (x2,0), is there a property with the slopes?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I was solving a problem and made up a conjecture based purely on intuition and want to prove it:

I have a circle A with the points (2,4), (4,4), and (2,0). I have another circle B with the points (2,4), (4,4), and (4,0).

First, I solved for the equations of the circles, then implicitly differentiated so I could:

find the slopes of the tangent lines at the point on the x-axis for both circles([2,0] for circle A and [4,0] for circle B).

I solved that the slopes of the tangent lines on the x axis is -1/2 for circle A and 1/2 for Circle B.

That got me thinking... is there some other point on the y-axis we could choose that, when formed a circle with (2,4) and (4,4), has a tangent line slope of 0?

I came up with a little conjecture that I feel is true but do not know how to go about proving it(it is worded poorly, sorry about that):
all values in the interval (-1/2,1/2) are slopes of tangent lines at (q,0) for a circle consisting of the three points: (2,4), (4,4), and (q,0), as long as q is between 2 and 4.

This conjecture is based purely on the fact that the slope of the tangent line is -1/2 when q = 2 and the slope of the tangent line is 1/2 when q = 4, so maybe the slope of the tangent line goes from -1/2 to 1/2 as q goes from 2 to 4?

So far I have tried to prove it using the Intermediate Value theorem but for that I need to show that the function of the slope of the circle is continuous, which I am not sure how to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The general strategy would be to determine the equation of the circle through $(2,4), (4,4), (q,0)$ (with unknown $q$), implicitly differentiate, then see if any value of $q$ in $[2,4]$ causes a discontinuity in the slope expression. If not, it's continuous. Though I'm not sure how challenging the algebra becomes.